# Topological group with discrete topology

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group. I came to know that if I can show the existence of a homeomorphism of $G$ which moves only finitely many points of $G$, then $G$ has only discrete topology.

How can I prove this ?

Comment: Is the group $G$ assume Hausdorff?

Comment: The claim is wrong, unless you add a) that $G$ is Hausdorff (otherwise consider for example the indisrete topology) and b) that the homeomorphism is not the identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**. We assume here that $G$ is a Hausdorff topological group.

Let us first prove the following assertion:

**Claim** If there exists a continuous $id\ne \psi:G\to G$ such that $\psi(x)\ne x$ for at most finitely many $x\in G$, then $G$ has a finite open subset.

*Proof*. Consider the function $f(x)=\psi(x)\cdot x^{-1}$. By assumption, $f(x)\ne 1$ for at most finitely many $x\in G$. Also, since $G$ is a topological group, and $\psi$ continuous, it is clear that $f$ is continuous. Since the point $1$ is closed, we have that $U=\lbrace x\mid f(x)\ne 1\rbrace= f^{-1}(G\setminus\lbrace 1\rbrace)$ is finite and open.

Since the group $G$ is Hausdorff (or even T1 would do, I think), you can use this to show that there exists an open singleton in $G$. From here the proof should be obvious (use the fact that group translations are homeomorphisms).

**Remark**. I don't see where the fact that $\psi$ is a homeomorphism was used. I think that this assumption can be weakened to just continuity, but if anyone sees something I missed please let me know.

Comment: "Since the point 1 is closed." uses that $G$ is Hausdorff. By the way, for topological groups the separation axioms T0, T1, T2 coincide.

Comment: Wait, @MartinBrandenburg .. are you sure about that? if you take $G=(\mathbb C,+)$ with the Zarisky topology, then $G$ is a topological group (since multiplication and inversion are polynomial mappings), but $\mathbb C$ is clearly $T_1$ and not $T_2$ with respect to Zarisky topology...

Comment: $(\mathbb{C},Zar) \times (\mathbb{C},Zar) \to (\mathbb{C},Zar), (x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is not continuous (in contrast to $(\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C},Zar) \to (\mathbb{C},Zar)$.)

Comment: The claim is trivial, every topological space has a finite open subset, $U=\emptyset$. Better add $\psi \neq \mathrm{id}$ and $U \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.. I guess I've gotten too used to the topology of the product being assume to be the zarisky product.

Regarding the last comment- nah.. I'll let the OP worry about that. Either he realizes it by himself or he proves that all topological groups are discrete. In my view it's a win-win situation :)